# How do I use BigInterger In my code for calculating primes?

Tags: java, primes

I'm using this basic and crude code below for calculating prime numbers then exporting them to a text file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class primeGenerator{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String prime;
        long num = kb.nextLong();
        long i;
        long z=0;
        while(z==0){

            for (i=2; i < num ;i++ ){
                long n = num%i;
                if (n==0){

                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i == num){
                writer(num);

            }
            num=num+2;
        }
    }

    public static void writer(long num) throws Exception {

           FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("prime.txt",true); 
           String prime= ""+ num;
           writer.write(prime);
           writer.write("   ");
           writer.flush();
           writer.close();


    }
}
```

I would like to find primes beyond the Primative long's range and apparently big integer is the way to go about it. So how do i alter my code to do so?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need this? Having numbers bigger than can be handled by *long* means you want to test numbers bigger than 9223372036854775807. If your for-loop can test a hundred million divisions per second, it will still take it 2923 years to determine if that number is prime - and longer for larger numbers, of course.

A common optimization is to only test divisions up to sqrt(num). If you haven't found anything then, the number is prime.

Comment: Also I'd recommend caching the primes you find and iterating over to avoid unnecessary divisions (e.g. if something is not divisable by 3 no point in dividing it by 9).

Answer (score 1):

Well, use `BigInteger` wherever you've currently got `long`. Instead of using `%` you'll use `mod`, instead of incrementing you'll use `i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)`, instead of == 0 you'll use `equals(BigInteger.ZERO)` etc.

Use `Scanner.nextBigInteger` instead of `Scanner.nextLong`, too.

Given that this looks like homework of some description (possibly self-set, of course) I won't write out the whole code for you - but if you have specific problems, feel free to ask.

Comment: One addition: BigInteger is immutable. This means if you do myBigInt.add(anotherBigInt) that the value of myBigInt has not changed. You need to copy the return value, as Jon shows above. Although this is clearly stated in the JavaDoc, I feel it warrents a heads up.